# C++ - XCode and Testing if a port is open

Tags: c++, macos, sockets, networking, tcp

So using winsock with c++ under windows is pretty simple. However, how does one do when you are using Xcode and c++ under mac to test if a port is open? In this case i'd like to check if the login server is up for my favorite game is up.

Is there a "native" way of doing this? Or does one have to rely on some other 3rd party library to get this working?

Example appriciated, allthough not required.

Comment: Use the standard Berkeley Sockets library: Call `socket()` and `connect()` and check for errors.

Comment: Ty Sir, did not know about that :) I seem not to be able to accept your answer though :o

Comment: Well, it's just a comment, not an answer. For a real answer, I feel I would need to present a complete code example, and I don't really have time at the moment. Don't worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to test for the availability of any resource is just to try to use it. Looking for tricks that will tell you ahead of time whether the attempted use will succeed are essentially exercises in fortune-telling. Just try it and catch the exception/handle the error code. You have to do that anyway: why do it all twice?

Comment: thats essentially what connect will do :) connection will report an error that you will catch onto if it was not able to connect, if it does not report an error, it has to be open.

Comment: @Hiam Exactly. So, just connect when you need to connect. No 'testing' about it. Just do it.

Comment: I agree with EJP, why check and then use, but what if you are only wanting to know if the port is up? For me, it would be useful as a dashboard utility for whether my 100 sites are up or down at any given moment. Not that I have to access each and everyone of them.

Comment: @user624661 when you are testing if a remote port is up the only real way is to connect to it.  There are port sniffing techniques that can identify is there port listeners on remove machines but to know if you can actually connect to the port, you have to actually do the connect.  So use the connect, if it fails then they are down, if it works, they are up. you don't want to send any data though.. just connect, then disconnect.